# Why are the method declarations not compatible?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Why do I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of ConcreteFooMapper::load() must be compatible with that of AbstractFooMapper::load() on line 18
```

from this code:

```
<?php
interface Foo {
    public function foo();
}

class ConcreteFoo implements Foo {
    public function foo() {

    }
}

abstract class AbstractFooMapper {
    abstract public function load(Foo $entity, array $data);
}

class ConcreteFooMapper extends AbstractFooMapper {
    public function load(ConcreteFoo $entity, array $data) {

    }
}
?>
```

My initial thought is that it's a bug; PHP isn't detecting that *ConcreteFoo* implements *Foo* when it is evaluating the method declaration it. I think this because when you run this code:

```
<?php
interface Foo {
    public function foo();
}

class ConcreteFoo implements Foo {
    public function foo() {

    }
}

$foo = new ConcreteFoo();

if ($foo instanceof Foo) 
{
    print 'w00t!';
} 
else 
{
    print 'FAIL!';
}
?>
```

it prints *w00t!* indicating *ConcreteFoo* is an instance of *Foo*.

Any insights into whether this behavior is correct or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error. And same rules for classes which extends abstract classes.

Please, see in [see in details here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), [see here too](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

And this is right behaviour \ logic.

[check here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_class) Abstract types are useful in that they can be used to define and enforce a protocol; a set of operations which all objects that implement the protocol must support.

if we assume that your code will  work without exception, then we have following problem: `ConcreteFooMapper` can't  use instances of some `class ConcreteFoo2 implements Foo` as parameter for `load` method, but should (by Abstract class definition)

Also,  if you use same signature, it not a problem really, cause all class \ type info available. Please, check following code

```php
<?php
interface Foo {
        public function foo();
}

class ConcreteFoo implements Foo {
        public function foo() {
        }
}

abstract class AbstractFooMapper {
        abstract public function load(Foo $entity, array $data);
}

class ConcreteFooMapper extends AbstractFooMapper {
        public function load(Foo $entity, array $data) {
                var_dump($entity instanceof Foo);
                var_dump($entity instanceof ConcreteFoo);
        }

}

$someConcreteFoo = new ConcreteFoo();
$someFooMapper = new ConcreteFooMapper();

$someFooMapper->load($someConcreteFoo, array('somekey' => 'somevalue'));
// output
// bool(true) bool(true)  

?>
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I was hoping to use type hinting to enforce only  instances of `ConcreteFoo` being passed in the `load` method of `ConcreteFooMapper`but now I see how that breaks the protocol/contract.

I'll just add the type check in at the beginning of the method using `instanceof`. It's what I've done in the past.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), type hints must match exactly.

Comment: OK; glad my understanding of polymorphism isn't wrong, just PHP's implementation of it.

Comment: Strengthening the predicate in the extended classes would violate Liskov's substitution principle; that's probably not the underlying reason, but it works for me :)

Comment: Wouldn't it adhere to the principle due to variance?

Comment: Php is behaving properly.  As written, some override of the method may accept something that only implements `Foo`, and some other may only accept `ConcreteFooMapper`.  That would not be correct polymorphism.  The override method could type hint for `Foo` and still accept an argument of type `Conrete...`.  If absolutely necessary, it could verify the class of the `Foo` implementer in its code.

Answer (score 0):

What's interesting is that you can strengthen the predicate using constructor:

```
// ABuilder.php

abstract class ABuilder
{
    public function __construct(BaseApi $api = null)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public static function fromArray(array $data, BaseApi $api = null)
    {
        $entity = new static($api);

        // ...

        return $entity;
    }
}

// ContactBuilder.php
class Contact extends ABuilder
{
    // here, you cannot change signature of ::fromArray to require ContactApi
    // (which extends/implements BaseApi), like in this example:
    public static function fromArray(array $data, ContactApi $api = null) {}

    // but you can specify ContactApi in the constructor arguments:
    public function __construct(ContactApi $api = null) {}
}
```

So, when you try to initialise your `ContactBuilder` class with wrong implementation of Api (even via `::fromArray()` fabric) — you'll get proper Type error message like:

> Argument 1 passed to Builder/Contact::__construct() must be an
> instance of ContactApi or null, instance of LeadApi given